# Strange thing happening with Java applet HTML page

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, applet

My Java applet works absolutely fine on my webpage, but a lot of strange code is also displayed. I'm using Internet Explorer, what is the problem?

Here is what is displayed on the page:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Arial;}} {\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2508;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20 \par \par
```

(applet)

```
/par/par/par}
```

And here is my html:

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code = "NameInLights.class" width = "500" height = "500">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question to determine whether it's browser specific (and it shouldn't be because it's JAVA), have you tried it in another browser like FF or Chrome? If so, do you have any problems there?

Comment: Only chrome, but had lots of problems with <object> tag. IE works better with applets in my experience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that's all there is in your HTML page. You must have created your HTML page using some kind of a Microsoft tool. That tool is inserting its claim to the fame, by putting its signon/copyright information. Open your HTML page, find the above string and carefully remove it.

Comment: Used WordPad - when opened, no string found. If opening on notepad, the string is there. Thx 4 the help, but why is this?

Comment: That string is in RTF format, since Wordpad understands the RTF, it understood and did not show it. All other stuff that do not care about RTF just pass through and you would see it.

Comment: I see. I shall use use Notepad in future. Thx 4 the help, accepting ur answer now :)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest notepad as your editor of choice. NotePad++ is  much better. It highlights code for you and can indicate syntax problems with the color coding.